# how to send data checbox from ajax to php

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I following this code, I want to send data checxbox to php, but this code only send data one by one. how to I can send data to php as much as select data one time send

```
$('#lunas').click(function(){
    $('#tampilkan tbody input:checked').each(function(){
        var id = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
        var nosam = id.cells[1].innerHTML;
        var unit = id.cells[2].innerHTML;
        var blthn = id.cells[8].innerHTML;
        var dd = Number(hapusTitik(id.cells[9].innerHTML));
        var rp = Number(hapusTitik(id.cells[10].innerHTML));
        var tgl = document.getElementById('tgl').value;

        $.ajax({
          url: 'get/penjualan_simpan.php',
          data: {'nosam': nosam, 'unit': unit, 'blthn': blthn, 'dd': dd, 'rp': rp, 'tgl': tgl},
          cache: false,
          success: function(data){
            $('#modalByar').modal('hide');
            }
          }
        });
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This should work as it is, yet you do have it sending an AJAX GET request for each checkbox. You might consider gathering all the data and then sending it once. Consider closing your `$.each()` and then sending the data all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you can use `map()` to build an array of objects from the checkboxes. You can then provide that array to the `data` property of the AJAX request. Then in your PHP code you can loop through that array and perform whatever actions you require on the data of each row. Try this:

```js
$('#lunas').on('click', function() {
  let data = $('#tampilkan tbody input:checked').map(function() {
    let $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    return {
      nosam: $row.find('td:eq(1)').text(),
      unit: $row.find('td:eq(2)').text(),
      blthn: $row.find('td:eq(8)').text(),
      dd: Number(hapusTitik($row.find('td:eq(9)').text())),
      rp: Number(hapusTitik($row.find('td:eq(10)').text())),
      tgl: $('#tgl').val()
    }
  }).get();

  $.ajax({
      url: 'get/penjualan_simpan.php',
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#modalByar').modal('hide');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I would also suggest you make this request using the POST verb instead of GET.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```
$('#lunas').click(function() {
  var myData = [];
  $('#tampilkan tbody input:checked').each(function(i, el) {
    var row = $(el).closest('tr');
    myData.push({
      nosam: $("td:eq(1)", row).html(),
      unit: $("td:eq(2)", row).html(),
      blthn: $("td:eq(8)", row).html(),
      dd: Number(hapusTitik($("td:eq(9)", row).html())),
      rp: Number(hapusTitik($("td:eq(10)", row).html())),
      rgl: $('#tgl').val()
    });
  });

  $.ajax({
      url: 'get/penjualan_simpan.php',
      method: "post",
      data: {
        checks: myData
      },
      cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
        $('#modalByar').modal('hide');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

This creates an array and each Row in your table then becomes an entry in the Array. It will be an Array of Objects, with each Object containing that rows details.

When in php, you will then receive a complex posted variable. You can access it like so:

```
var_export($_POST['checks']);
```

This should show you all the data that was posted. Each of the Rows and Each of the Cells.